# Add UIView to ContentView in a TableViewCell using constraints

Tags: ios

I am trying to add cells to UITableView using Constraints. Do you know how. The following just gives:

[image]

And says: Height is ambiguous for UIView

Do you know how to add a UIView to ContextView using constraints - note the fixed height in the constraints.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"Cell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }

        let view = UIView(frame: cell!.frame)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        let constraintTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell!.contentView,
                                               attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top,
                                               relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                               toItem: view,
                                               attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top,
                                               multiplier: 1,
                                               constant: 0)

        let constraintLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell!.contentView,
                                                   attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading,
                                                   relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                                   toItem: view,
                                                   attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading,
                                                   multiplier: 1,
                                                   constant: 0)

        let constraintTrailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell!.contentView,
                                                    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing,
                                                    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                                    toItem: view,
                                                    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing,
                                                    multiplier: 1,
                                                    constant: 0)

        let constraintHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell!.contentView,
                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height,
                                                  relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                                  toItem: nil,
                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height,
                                                  multiplier: 1, constant: 50) // << Note fixed height

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        cell?.contentView.addSubview(view)
        cell?.contentView.addConstraints([constraintTop, constraintLeading, constraintTrailing, constraintHeight])

        return cell!
    }


}
```

Tried to change constraints to include bottom of the contentView:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"Cell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }

        let view = UIView(frame: cell!.frame)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        let constraintTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell!.contentView,
                                               attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top,
                                               relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                               toItem: view,
                                               attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top,
                                               multiplier: 1,
                                               constant: 0)

        let constraintLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell!.contentView,
                                                   attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading,
                                                   relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                                   toItem: view,
                                                   attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading,
                                                   multiplier: 1,
                                                   constant: 0)

        let constraintTrailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell!.contentView,
                                                    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing,
                                                    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                                    toItem: view,
                                                    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing,
                                                    multiplier: 1,
                                                    constant: 0)

        let constraintBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell!.contentView,
                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom,
                                                  relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                                  toItem: view,
                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom,
                                                  multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell?.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(view)
        cell?.contentView.addConstraints([constraintTop, constraintLeading, constraintTrailing, constraintBottom])

        return cell!
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a couple things wrong.

First, you are setting the constraints backward. You want to constrain your new `view` to the `contentView`:

```
let constraintTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view,  // constrain this view
                           attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top,
                           relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                           toItem: cell?.contentView,  // to this view
                           attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top,
                           multiplier: 1,
                           constant: 0)
```

Second, don't do this:

```
cell?.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Third, your code is (well, will be) adding a new "orange view" every time the cell is reused. Much better to add subviews in the init portion of a custom cell class, but if you're going to do it in `cellForRow`, check if it's already there first:

```
    if cell.contentView.subviews.count == 0 {
        // no, so add it here

        let view = UIView()

        // continue with view setup
```

Fourth, you may find it easier / more logical / cleaner / etc to add constraints this way:

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(view)

view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
```

And... since you have registered a cell class for reuse, this format will give you a valid cell:

```
    // instead of this
    //var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
    //if cell == nil {
    //  cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    //}

    // better method
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
```

---

So, here is the full function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    // have we already added the subview?
    if cell.contentView.subviews.count == 0 {
        // no, so add it here

        let view = UIView()

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        cell.contentView.addSubview(view)

        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your fourth constraint is applying a fixed height to the contentView. What you want instead is to pin the bottom edges of the contentView and your custom `view` (like you did with leading/top/trailing) *and* apply the constant height constraint to `view`, not `contentView`. `contentView` simply adapts to its subviews, you don't tell it its height directly.

Additionally, in your `viewDidLoad`, you'll want to set your `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, since you're calculating the height via constraints.

Also, you will run into problems because this code is in `cellForRow`. This function is called every time a new cell comes onscreen, which means as you scroll, you're going to reuse the same views and have duplicate extra views added. I recommend you subclass `UITableViewCell` and put this code in its `init`.

Comment: Thanks, good info. I tried to change the height constraint to bottom constraint(see updated code). I still dont see any orange view?

Comment: You need the fixed height constraint on your `view`. Also see my edit about `tableView.rowHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solutions is: Read the "Output"!

```
Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of the contentView of a UITableViewCell is not supported and will result in undefined behavior, as this property is managed by the owning UITableViewCell
```

Having the following messed it all up:

cell?.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Remove this line and it will work.